# Image Cropping to get just the particular shape out of image

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv

[I have the images as below, i need to extract just the white strip portion from all the images.
i Have tried using PIL to extract the rectangular portion by manually specifying the pixel value, Can there be any automated way to get this work done where by just feeding the image gives back the rectangular portion

Below is My snipped code:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('C:/Users/ShAgarwal/Documents/image_dataset/pic9.jpg')
half_the_width = img.size[0] / 2
half_the_height = img.size[1] / 2

img4 = img.crop(
    (
        half_the_width-1632,
        half_the_height - 440,
        half_the_width+1632,
        half_the_height + 80
    )
)
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN67v.jpg)

Comment: Zdar please click on the sample image link just below my snipped code and you will be able to see the image

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image='IMG_3134.JPG'
# read image
imgc = cv2.imread(image)
img = cv2.resize(imgc, None, fx=0.25, fy=0.25) # resize since image is huge
#cropping the strip dimensions
#crop_img = img[1010:1650,140:1099723]
blurred = cv2.blur(img, (3,3))
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200)
```

Marking coordinates through auto image detection using canny's algorithm

```
## find the non-zero min-max coords of canny
pts = np.argwhere(canny>0)
y1,x1 = pts.min(axis=0)
y2,x2 = pts.max(axis=0)`
`## crop the region
cropped = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", cropped)
#Select the bounded area around white boundary
tagged = cv2.rectangle(img.copy(), (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
r = cv2.selectROI(tagged)
imCrop = im[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]
#Bounded Area
cv2.imwrite("taggd2.png", imcrop)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[Results from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D6nL.png)